# Написание буквы Ъ

Tags: орфография

Есть ли какие-то правила употребления твердого знака?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Твердый знак пишется только перед буквами Е, Ю и Я, если:
- приставка заканчивается на согласную, а корень на одну из этих гласных.
Примеры: *подъезд, объедение, побъет*.
- В сложных словах после приставок, обозначающих количество.
Примеры: *двухъярусный, трехъядерный*.
-В иноязычных словах, после приставок:  аб-, ад-, диз-, ин-, интер-, кон-, контр-, об-, суб-, транс- и частицы пан-.
Примеры: *адъютант, инъекция, объект*.

Answer (score 0):

Если вкратце, это как арабская хамза - гортанная смычка, только у нас она нужна для отделения частей в слове (подъезд и подезд были бы разными вещами), а у них она стоит в конце и обрывает долгие гласные (у некоторых вроде ливанского арабского ещё и вместо "qаф", ибо нефиг). Такие дела.